# Error Jabber::ClientAuthenticationFailure: not-authorized using xmpp4r and openfire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openfire, xmpp4r

I am using Openfire and xmpp4r to connect to server with the help of [tutorial](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/xmpp4r-a-real-world-example/). This tutorial is working fine for everyone except me, its throwing error on line

```
@client.auth(@password)
```

Error is

```
Jabber::ClientAuthenticationFailure: not-authorized
from /home/haider/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/xmpp4r-0.5.6/lib/xmpp4r/client.rb:120:in `rescue in auth'
from /home/haider/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/xmpp4r-0.5.6/lib/xmpp4r/client.rb:109:in `auth'
from (irb):32
from /home/haider/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /home/haider/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/haider/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /home/haider/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!
```

I Google and found a [solution](https://www.innoq.com/blog/vd/2008/07/cutting_corners.html) which resolve similar problem appending resource name with JID but this too is not working for Openfire

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: @ManishShrivastava Yes i think I have found it .....

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:

https://github.com/xmpp4r/xmpp4r/issues/42

Basically, call this instead of vanilla auth method:

`client.auth_sasl SASL.new(client, 'PLAIN'), password`

As to why SASL + digest doesn't work with new-ish Openfire, I am unsure.